# Implementing Search on a UITableView which is getting results from Firebase DB

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which gets data from a Firebase Realtime Database. I need to add search for the list, the data fetched is of class called `Post`. Once the user clicks on the cell, it passes the data to a Detailed View Controller. The search is not currently working because it's searching on a `NSDictionary` instead of the `Post`, also I'm unsure on how to go about it.

```
class PostTable: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {


func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    print(searchController.searchBar.text)
}

func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
    // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
    return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {
    print("Search Text = " + searchText)
    filteredPosts = filteredPosts.filter({( post : Post) -> Bool in
        print(post.title.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
        return post.title.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    })

    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
    let user : Post

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        user = filteredPosts[indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
    }
    return cell
}


@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var searchActive : Bool = false

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
var posts = [Post]()

var filteredPosts = [Post]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        switchStoryboard()
    }

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
    var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.reloadData()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    observePosts()
}

func switchStoryboard() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let vc: UIViewController? = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        var window: UIWindow? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window)!
        window?.rootViewController = vc
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func observePosts() {
    let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("Data").queryOrdered(byChild: "priority")
    print(postsRef)
    postsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        var tempPosts = [Post]()

        for child in snapshot.children{

            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let title = dict["title"] as? String,
                let logoImage = dict["image"] as? String,
                let url = URL(string:logoImage),
                let address = dict["address"] as? String,
                let contact = dict["contact"] as? String,
                let description = dict["description"] as? String{


                let userProfile = UserProfile(title: title, photoURL: url)
                let post = Post(id: childSnapshot.key, title: userProfile, description: description, image: userProfile, address: address, contact: contact)
                print(post)
                tempPosts.append(post)
            }
        }

        self.posts = tempPosts
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}


func getImage(url: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
        if error == nil {
            completion(UIImage(data: data!))
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
        }.resume()
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != ""{
       return filteredPosts.count
   } else {
       return posts.count
   }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let postsInfo = posts[indexPath.row]
    print(postsInfo)

    let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let DvC = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostTableDetailed") as! PostTableDetailed
    DvC.getName = postsInfo.title.title
    DvC.getDesc = postsInfo.description
    DvC.getImg = postsInfo.title.photoURL.absoluteString
    DvC.getAddress = postsInfo.address
    DvC.getContact = postsInfo.contact

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DvC, animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: The code looks like copied and pasted together from several sources. The type of the data source array and the *filtered* array must be the same. And don't use `NS...` collection types in Swift at all. Filtering a custom struct or class is much more efficient.

Comment: you are not set the conttent of the cell when the searchBar is active, so you must do something,in your code is not clear, you are using the same cell for both case so the cell must admit a user type to configureit self in set function, but you dont

Comment: @vadian I'm passing the `searchText` into a new function which takes in the type `Post`, but it's unable to reload data for the table. I'm adding the code, it will be really helpful if you'd have a look at it.

Comment: But where does `usersArray` and `filteredUsers` come from if you want to filter posts?

Comment: @vadian I cleared them off as I'm not using dictionary anymore, I'm only using `posts` and `filteredPosts` because they're the same type. I'm trying to access the `title` from the `Post` and to perform the search on that string.

Comment: Please edit the question and apply the cleared code. Basically the code is supposed to work if you are using the proper arrays

Comment: @vadian Just edited the question, and posted the cleared code of the View Controller

Answer (score 1):

`cellForRow` is wrong

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    let post = searchController.isActive ? filteredPosts[indexPath.row] : posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.set(post: post)
    return cell
}
```

It's sufficient to check for `searchController.isActive`.

---

And you have to filter `posts` not `filteredPosts`. I changed also the signature of `filterContentForSearchText` to conform to the naming guidelines.

```
func filterContent(for searchText: String) {
    filteredPosts = posts.filter{ $0.title.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

And be aware that `didSelectRowAt` can crash or cause unexpected behavior when the `searchController` is active.

Comment: Yeah, it gives Index out of range when I try to search something. I'm trying to make it work right now.